# How to make TinyMce work with multiple array name textareas?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tinymce, textarea

I have a form with 2 textareas, one per language. The names as array are needed in order to process theme via php and then serialize. So "text[it]" and "text[en]" must have the same prefix, in this case "text".. but they could be "description[it]" and "description[en]" as well:

```
<textarea name="text[it]" id="one" class="tinymce"></textarea>

<textarea name="text[en]" id="two" class="tinymce"></textarea>
```

When I paste, it puts the text twice.

How can I make the tinymce consider them as two different textareas?

I cannot find the solution.

Here the js I use:

```
<script src="/.../tinymce4012/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector:'.tinymce',
            plugins:'table,code,paste,image',
              plugins: [
              "table,code,paste,image",
              "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
              "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
              "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages"
              ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",
            tools:'inserttable,image',
            relative_urls: false,
            language : 'it',
            paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
            paste_remove_styles: true,
            paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
            paste_strip_class_attributes: true,
            imagemanager_contextmenu: true,
        });
</script>
```

I think it could be usefull to tell TinyMce js to consider the IDs and not the name as they look like the same for it (in fact when I past something Tiny insert in the textarea the content I paste, twice). But how? Or what's the solution?

Second, I have only the min js version of TinyMce. How can I can find the developer version so I can edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors are fine. The issue is that you have included the `"paste"` plugin twice:

```
plugins: [
      "table,code,paste,image", //<< Included here
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
      "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages" //<<Included here
              ]
```

get rid of the second include and you should be fine.